Blazor printing to Zebra printer from client side without any side application
I want to send raw ZPL commands to a Zebra printer from a Blazor web application (on client side). This printer is not accessible from the Blazor server app. Is it possible to print with the Zebra printer only on client side without installation of any helper application/service which manages the print jobs on the client PC?

Most zebra printers have built-in http servers that you can use with an XMLHttpRequest.  See https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/HTTP-Post-printing-sample?language=en_US for more details.

And what if user does not know the IP address?
